# There are 7 types of marbles with numbers from 0 to 9 in one box, what is the probability that I draw marbles the same numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

> There are 7 marbles, each marble has a label with a number, from 0 to 9. There are 7 types of marbles. for example,

1st type of marbles,  $(0, 1, ..., 9)$

2nd type of marbles $(0, 1, ..., 9) $

...

...

7th type of marbles $(0, 1, ..., 9) $

> All 70 marbles are mixed in one box. I draw 7 marbles without replacement (they are all in the same box), what is the probability that I draw 7 marbles with the same number?

I'm asking this question, because I don't have the answer,

I did this procedure:

I've used the complement rule, $$P(A) = 1- P(A^c)$$
$P(A^c)$ can be found this way: I know that A is the event of drawing 7 marbles with the same number, and the complement is equal to the event of drawing 7 marbles with different numbers. it's a partial permutation (without repetitions), and the denominator (i.e the sample space cardinality) is equal to $n^k$, because it's a permutation with repetitions . Let me know if it's correct:
$$ P(A) = 1 - (\frac{\frac{70!}{63!}}{70^7}) $$ the final result is
$0.2664$

Comment: Do you mix all 70 balls in one box or separate them into 7 boxes and draw one ball from each box?

Comment: I've mixed all 70 balls

Comment: It is not correct: done this way the denominator would be $\frac{70!}{63!}$ as the number of ways of drawing $7$ balls from $70$ without replacement and the numerator much smaller.  Alternatively the denominator could be ${70 \choose 7}$ and the numerator even smaller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 10 cases satisfying the purpose. seven $0$'s, seven $1$'s,..., seven $9$'s.

$$P(A)=\frac{10}{\binom{70}{7}}$$

Comment: is this the complement?

Comment: no, it is P(A).

Comment: shouldn't be $\frac{7}{\binom{70}{7}}$? because there are 7 balls with the same number, and 10 balls with different numbers

Comment: so you have "seven 0", "seven 1", ..., "seven 9", totally 10 cases

Comment: and these 10 cases are different, they have not the same numbers

Comment: surely they are different cases, so you count 10. But for each case, the # on the marble are the same. Don't confuse.

Comment: "so you count 10" why you count 10?

Comment: "seven 0", count 1, "seven 1", count 2, ..."seven 9", count 10